# make mysql to share all cpu

Tags: linux, centos, mysql, memory

I am very new to linux server .I am using centos.Sometimes my cpu gets overloaded because of the process mysqld over 100%

```
PID   USER   PR    NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S    %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
2221    mysql  20     0     2810m   797m  5648 S   99.3  5.0  262:15.91   mysqld
```

So To debug I ran **top** command in ssh and I got below

```
Cpu(s):  2.9%us,  2.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 94.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  16291440k total, 14893024k used,  1398416k free,  1673232k buffers
Swap: 16433144k total,    30168k used, 16402976k free, 10713048k cached
```

I dont understand anything in this but i see , Only one CPU (94.7%id) is used alot and other CPU are free.How to make mysql to share more cpu and reduce the load.

Comment: `94.7%id` means the system spends 94.7% of its time doing nothing (id=idle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Row 3 :** in **top** command indicates **how the cpu is used**. Understand each one separately

```
% of the CPU for user processes (2.9%us)
% of the CPU for system processes (2.3%sy)
% of the CPU processes with priority upgrade nice (0.0%ni)
% of the CPU not used (94.7%id)
% of the CPU processes waiting for I/O operations(0.0%wa)
% of the CPU serving hardware interrupts (0.0% hi)
% of the CPU serving software interrupts (0.1% si)
```

---

**Row 4 and 5:** Gives RAM (physical memory) and SWAP details.

---

This shows the **Processes List**

```
%CPU – % of CPU used by this process (99.3)
%MEM – % of RAM used by the process (5.0)
```

---

For CPU allocation refer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14787046/how-to-allocate-more-cpu-and-ram-to-a-c-program-in-linux

https://askubuntu.com/questions/115478/how-do-i-assign-different-cpu-cores-to-different-processes